# Is PKCS#12 structure without integrity protection against the specification?

Tags: standards

PKCS#12 contains 2 integrity protection modes: password-based and public-key based. The way this is done in the standard is that data layout wise it appears to be fine to skip integrity protection because the `macData` field (used for the password-based integrity mode) in the outer structure is OPTIONAL to make way for the public-key mode (which stores the signature used for integrity verification using the `signedData` type field inside the `authSafe` field) as noted on https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/17720#issuecomment-1043064166

However, RFC 7292 says in the introduction section:

> This standard supports direct transfer of personal information under
> several privacy and integrity modes.  The most secure of the privacy
> and integrity modes require the source and destination platforms to
> have trusted public/private key pairs usable for digital signatures
> and encryption, respectively.  The standard also supports lower-
> security, password-based privacy and integrity modes for those cases
> where trusted public/private key pairs are not available.

There is no word about privacy-less or integrity-less modes.

So, to me it seems the choices given in section-3.1 where the individual modes are actually described are either/or. Does the standard really allow for the integrity-less mode ?

Perhaps my question should be maybe rephrased as "against the spirit/intention of the specification".